# Are sub collections in Firestore visible on the base document read/write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am wondering if it is safe to store sensitive user data in collections of documents (see structure below) and using the Firestore.rules (see rules below) to gate specific users from accessing a collection inside a document? If I run a `get` instruction on a user document, will the private collection be accessible? Or is it only accessible if I call a get instruction on the `address` document (for example)?

Sorry if this is up somewhere on the web, but I couldn't find a definitive answer and this is somewhat important to the integrity of my app. I wanted to get a good idea before I restructure my backend.

**Firestore Structure:**

```
(collection) users: {
    (document) ID1234567890: {
        (collection) private: {
            (document) address: {
              line1: "",
              line2: "",
              city: "",
              state: "", 
              zip: "",
              country: "",
            },
            (document) billing: {
              ssnLast4: "",
              externalAccount: {},
            },
            (document) signatures: {
              ...
            }
        }
        id: "",
        userName: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        avatarUrl: "",
        ...
        phone: "",
        email: "",
    }
}
```

**Firestore.rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    // Users collection // 
    // TODO: does this match give access to all sub collections?
    match /users/{userId} {
      function isTrueUser() {
        return resource.data.id == request.auth.uid;
      }
      // Anyone can create a user
      allow create: if true;
      // Only signed in users can read or list user profile data
      allow read, list: if isSignedIn();
      // Only that user can update their profile data
      allow update: if isSignedIn() && isTrueUser();
      // No one can delete a user
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /users/{userId}/private/{documentName} {
      function isTrueUser() {
        return userId == request.auth.uid;
      }
      // Only that signed in user can create, update, read, or list their private documents
      allow create, update, read, list: if isSignedIn() && isUserOwner();
      // No one can delete a private document
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read operations in Firestore are shallow. So reads on a parent document don't automatically read the data from subcollections. You will need to do a separate read operation for each subcollection.

Having read access to a parent document does also not automatically mean that you can read the subcollections of that document. You can secure access to the subcollections in security rules.

Your current rules only matches documents in the `/users` collection:

```
match /users/{userId}
```

To make it also match the subcollections (which you **don't** want to do), it'd have to be:

```
match /users/{userId=**}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securing hierarchical data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data), specifically the section on [recursive wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards).